# Changing Sort in SwiftData

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-data

I'm converting a basic ToDo list app to SwiftData. I had previously used the EditButton() and allowed elements in the ToDo list to be moved to be reordered, but with SwiftData it'd likely make more sense to allow the user to sort a list based on various options, e.g.:

- As Entered
- Alphabetical
- Due Date
- Completed
  If I create an array of my todo items using @Query like this:

  @Query var toDos: [ToDoItem]

is it possible to add and change a sort parameter for the Query? I've added a Segmented Control on the bottom with enums for the various choices, but am unclear how I'd update the sort parameter on an existing Query item. Similarly, it would be nice to add or remove a predicate to filter on, say, showing only completed or not completed values.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Send the value you want to use to set the query and recreate the query in the view's initializer. The following is an example I'm preparing for my book. After this initializer is implemented, the view receives a string and a new query is created to search for that string.

```
   @Query var listBooks: [Book]
   
   init(search: String) {
      var predicate = #Predicate<Book> { _ in true }
      if !search.isEmpty {
         predicate = #Predicate<Book> { book in
            book.title.contains(search)
         }
      }
      _listBooks = Query<Book, [Book]>(filter: predicate, sort: \.title, order: .forward)
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a beginner but all I can tell you is that you can sort a query like that:

```
@Query(sort: \ToDoItem.'theVariableYouWantToUseToSort') private var todos: [ToDoItem]
```

Just replace 'theVariableYouWantToUseToSort' by the variable that you want to use to sort your todos.

I hope it helps you. Have a good day.

Comment: Is it also possible to change the sorting e.g. with a button click?

Comment: This is not the correct answer, as it is a static @query but the question was to "change a sort parameter". The only way of doing this with SwiftData at the moment is to create Query in an init() method of a "subview"